# Date Format Changed when uploaded to Server

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

There seems to be a slight issue with date formatting.

localhost displays the correct date format but when i uploaded it to web server the format has changed and i have no clue why its happening.

**Here is the SQL query**

```
SELECT Top 4 format$([Date],'Long Date') AS Date1, left([e_notice],170) AS e_notice from enotice ORDER BY date DESC
```

On Localhost it shows in this format  **Monday, June 24, 2013**

On Web Server it shows in this format  **June-24-13**

PS: i haven't defined date format in the database, database stores dates like this (24/06/2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results of using date format specifiers like "Long Date", "Short Date", etc. will depend on the settings for those presets in Windows' Regional Settings for the account under which the application runs. In your case those settings on the server are different from those on your local machine.

If you really want a particular format then you should explicitly specify it, e.g. something like

```
Format(Date(), "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy")
```

...should give you

```
Tuesday, July 2, 2013
```

Comment: Thank you Gord. Issue has been fixed ;)